# Sqlite3 problema con valores duplicados

Tags: sql, sqlite3

.Tablas involucradas:

data_incidencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

data_ticket

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intento ejecutar este query:

```
select t1.fecha_carga, t1.hurtos, t2.fallas, t3.ticket
                                from (select count(ttc) as hurtos, fecha_carga from data_incidencia
                                where campo_key_id = 2
                                group by fecha_carga) t1,
                                (select count(ttc) as fallas, fecha_carga from data_incidencia
                                where campo_key_id = 1
                                group by fecha_carga) t2,
                                (select count(ticket) as ticket, fecha_solicitud as fecha_carga from data_ticket ) t3 where t1.fecha_carga = t2.fecha_carga;
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el esperado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Diría que el resultado es el correcto. No has enlazado la `fecha_solicitud` de `data_ticket` con ninguna otra fecha. Prueba de la siguiente manera a ver que tal:

```
select t1.fecha_carga, t1.hurtos, t2.fallas, t3.ticket
                                from (select count(ttc) as hurtos, fecha_carga from data_incidencia
                                where campo_key_id = 2
                                group by fecha_carga) t1,
                                (select count(ttc) as fallas, fecha_carga from data_incidencia
                                where campo_key_id = 1
                                group by fecha_carga) t2,
                                (select count(ticket) as ticket, fecha_solicitud as fecha_carga from data_ticket ) t3 where t1.fecha_carga = t2.fecha_carga and t2.fecha_carga = t3.fecha_carga;
```